# Time Complexity of Subset Generation Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

The algorithmic complexity for the following code is O(2^n)

```
def genSubsets(L):
    res = []
    if len(L) == 0:
        return [[]]
    smaller = genSubsets(L[:-1]) # find all subsets without last element
    extra = L[-1:] # create a list of just last element
    new = []
    for small in smaller:
        new.append(small+extra) # for all smaller solutions, add one with last element
    return smaller + new # combine those with last element and those without

# Given explanation: For a list of size n there are 2^n cases ---> O(2^n) <huh?>
```

I don't understand how there are 2^n cases for a list of length n.

This is my understanding:

- a list of length n will make n recursive calls (each call passing in a list without the last element --> done until empty list [ ]).  This is O(n) complexity
- then you begin to make your way up the recursive calls
- as you move up, the number of subproblems solved ("smaller" list) increases thus the amount looping done in each recursive call increases
- "smaller" list sizes (starting from the deepest recursive call): 0, 1, 2, 4, 8,16 ...
- total number of operations 0 + 1 + 2 + 4 + ...2^n (since there are n recursion)
- O(2^n)

Does this explanation make sense? (Lol I sort of answered my questions as I wrote this, but some outside knowledge would be helpful XD )

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how there are 2^n cases for a list of length n.

- Ok, in this case, to check for every possible subset, we either `take the current element` in iteration or we `don't take current element` in iteration.
- This brings us 2 cases for each element -> Take or Not take.

  For the below tree, I will represent `take` as `T` and `Don't take` as `DT`.

Let's consider this array => `[1,3,5]`.
Recursion tree looks something like this-

```
                               Start state
                               /          \
                              /            \
                             /              \
                          T-1                DT-1
                         /   \               /   \
                        /     \             /     \
                       /       \           /       \
                      /         \         /         \
                     T-3      DT-3      T-3         DT-3
                    / \        /  \      / \         /  \
                   /   \      /    \    /   \       /    \
                  T-5  DT-5 T-5  DT-5  T-5  DT-5   T-5   DT-5
```

- As you can see from the above tree, there are **2<sup>3</sup>** leaves defining **2<sup>3</sup> subset possibilities**. You can make such recursion trees for inputs larger than size 3 to understand why complexity is exponential (**2<sup>n</sup>**) in this case.
- You can detect any subset from this tree by traversing from root to each leaf.

  For example- `[Start state,T-1,DT-3,T-5]` means subset `[1,5]`.